# Recurrence relation - simple question. Homework. Permutations with a twist,

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, permutations

I think I solved it but I would love someone to tell me if I'm wrong.

the question is as follows:

$n$ people are sitting on a bench with $n$ seats. Find a recursive equation that calculates how many different combinations are there to change the sitting order where every person can only move to the adjacent seat.

For example, if I'm sitting in chair number 4, I can only move to chair number 3, number 2, or stay where I am.

Next question: Same thing, but instead of on a bench, they are sitting around a round table.

**My solution:**

let $f(n)$ be the number of ways to rearrange the sitting as required. the first person has 2 options, either stay in his seat, or move to the sit next to him (he has only 1 sit next to him if its a bench), and the other people on the bench have $f(n-1)$ options. So overall : $f(n)=f(n-1)+2$

And if they are sitting at a round table: Same idea. the first person has $3$ options now. move right, move left, or stay where he is. overall: $f(n)=f(n-1)+3$

Comment: How come you can move from chair number 4 to number 2? They aren't adjacent, are they?

Comment: Why don't you work out the values of f(n) for the first values of n, by direct count? Then you would have something to test your recurrence equation on. I tried that and I don't think your equation works. For the bench problem I get f(1)=1 and f(2)=2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's give it a try.

$f(1) = 1$ as the only option is not to move. $f(2) = 2$ as the two people can exchange seats, or not move. Note that these are true for both bench and circle. $f(3) = 3$ for bench ($123 \to 213$ or $\to 132$ or $\to 123$) and $6$ for circle (new ones are $123 \to 321$ and $\to 231$ and $\to 312$).

In other words, you didn't get it right. Try again.

**Hint**. On a bench, if $1$ wants to go to $2$, $2$ *must* go to $1$. Otherwise the seat would stay empty.

Comment: Yes it seems  I was wrong...But for the love of god, I just can't figure out what the formula is. In either case. I thought maybe for the bench its $f(n)=1+f(n-1)$ but it's not. The numbers fit fibonnaci (at least up to n=5) but i don't know how to show it.

Comment: @OriaGruber, either $1$ doesn't move and you have $f(n-1)$ options left or $1$ moves to $2$ and $2$ moves to $1$ and you have $f(n-2)$ options left.